# Non-restoring division algorithm- dividend is smaller than divisor

Tags: mips

I'm attempting to divide 10111110 by 11000101 using the non-restoring division algorithm.

Note that the dividend is smaller than the divisor.

Following the flowchart used in the tutorials I've watched, I end up with a (seemingly) nonsensical result. It's possible I just don't know how to interpret my results properly.

Would appreciate help understanding how to use the non-restoring division algorithm in cases such as this.

Here is my attempt using the flowchart:

> ```
> A = Q = 190 = 10111110
> B = M = 197 = 11000101
> ```

```
Desc        A           Q           N
Init        00000000    10111110    8
shl         00000001    01111100    
A<A-M       00111100    01111100    
Q0=1, N-1   00111100    01111101    7
shl         01111000    11111010    
A<A-M       10110011    11111010    
Q0=0, N-1   10110011    11111010    6
shl         01100111    11110101    
A<A-M       10100010    11110101    
Q0=0, N-1   10100010    11110100    5
shl         01000101    11101001    
A<A-M       00110010    11101001    
Q0=1, N-1   00110010    11101001    4
shl         01100101    11010010    
A<A-M       10100000    11010010    
Q0=0, N-1   10100000    11010010    3
shl         01000001    10100101    
A<A-M       01111100    10100101    
Q0=1, N-1   01111100    10100101    2
shl         11111001    01001010    
A<A+M       10111110    01001010    
Q0=0, N-1   10111110    01001010    1
shl         01111100    10010101    
A<A-M       10110111    10010101    
Q0=0, N-1   10110111    10010100    0
A<A+M       01111100    10010100    
END
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you overlooked the requirement that partial remainder and denominator *need twice the word width of* numerator and quotient (cf. [Non-restoring division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Non-restoring_division)) and that using only 8 bits for e. g. `A` is the reason for the seemingly nonsensical result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I understand correctly, I am to add padding 0's (in this case 8 of them) to the accumulator. Is this correct?

Comment: Well, for partial remainder and denominator you'd need two registers, wouldn't you?