# non-restoring division: how to avoid code bloat for divisor MSB set?

Tags: assembly, avr, integer-division

Revisiting 32-bit integer division on AVR 8-bit processors, I tried to code unsigned non-restoring division. Not thinking it looks too bad, there is one problem:
With a divisor with highest bit set, it does not readily result in a quotient 0 where necessary.

Boiled down to 8-bit division, and followed by some libgcc code:

```
#define bits __zero_reg__
#define R r25
#define D r22
#define NQ r24
    ldi NQ, 25
    ldi r22, 129
__udivmodqi4NR:             ; 19 instructions NQ, R = divmod(NQ, D)
    clr     R
    ldi     bits, 8
    lsl     NQ
_udivmodqi4_pos:
    rol     R               ;   1
    sub     R, D            ;   2 diminish remainder
    brcs    _udivmodqi4_nep ; 4/3 remainder got < 0, was < divisor
    sec                     ;   4 How to obviate this?
_udivmodqi4_ep:
    rol     NQ              ;   5 rotate 1 quotient bit into dendQuot
    dec     bits            ;   6 decrement loop counter
    brne    _udivmodqi4_pos ; 8/7
    ret  
_udivmodqi4_neg:
    rol     R               ;   1
    add     R, D            ;   2 increase remainder
    brcs    _udivmodqi4_ep  ; 4/3 remainder restored to >= 0
_udivmodqi4_nep:
    lsl     NQ              ; 4/5 shift 0 quotient bit into dendQuot
    dec     bits            ; 5/6 decrement loop counter
    brne    _udivmodqi4_neg ; 7/6/8
    add     R, D
    ret
sleep
; libgcc (or close enough), 12 instructions, worst case not significantly slower:
#define r_rem   r25 /* remainder */
#define r_arg1  r24 /* dividend, quotient */
#define r_arg2  r22 /* divisor */
#define q_cnt   r23 /* loop count */
__udivmodqi4:               ; r24, r25 = divmod(r24, r22)
    sub     r_rem, r_rem    ; clear remainder and carry
    ldi     q_cnt, 8        ; init loop counter
    lsl     r_arg1
__udivmodqi4_loop:
    rol     r_rem           ;   1 shift dividend into remainder
    cp      r_rem, r_arg2   ;   2 compare remainder & divisor
    brcs    __udivmodqi4_ep ; 4/3 remainder <= divisor
    sub     r_rem, r_arg2   ;   4 restore remainder
__udivmodqi4_ep:
    rol     r_arg1          ;   5 shift dividend (with CARRY)
    dec     q_cnt           ;   6 decrement loop counter
    brne    __udivmodqi4_loop;8/7
    com     r_arg1          ;  67 complement result 
                        ; because C flag was complemented in loop
    ret
sleep

#define quotient    __tmp_reg__
#define byteCnt     __zero_reg__  /* loop count (0 after the loop!) */
#define dividend    r_arg1HH
zeroOne:; 11(movw)/7(mov) + 2 instructions just to handle divisor MSB == 1
    mov_l   r_remL , r_arg1L    ; remainder = dividend, part one
    mov_h   r_remH , r_arg1H
    mov_l   r_arg1L, r_remHL    ; quotient = 0
    mov_h   r_arg1H, r_remHH
    mov_l   r_remHL , r_arg1HL  ; part two
    mov_h   r_remHH , r_arg1HH
    mov_l   r_arg1HL, r_arg1L
    mov_h   r_arg1HH, r_arg1H
    ldi     byteCnt, 1          ; initialise loop control variables
    ldi     quotient, 0x80      ;  for a single/final iteration
    rjmp    subtract

__udivmodsi4NonRestoring:       ; arg2, arg1 = divmod(arg1, arg2)
    clr     r_remHH
    clr     r_remHL
    cpi     r_arg2HH, 128       ; sbrc r_arg2HH, 7   rjmp
    brsh    zeroOne             ; how to avoid special casing divisor MSB set?
    mov_l   r_remL , r_remHL
    mov_h   r_remH , r_remHH
    ldi     byteCnt, 4
    ldi     quotient, 1         ; takes NBBY(8) rol instructions to appear as carry

_udivmodsi4_pos:
    lsl     dividend            ;  1
    rol     r_remL              ;  2 shift dividend into remainder
    rol     r_remH              ;  3
    rol     r_remHL             ;  4
    rol     r_remHH             ;  5
subtract:
    sub     r_remL, r_arg2L     ;  6 diminish remainder
    sbc     r_remH, r_arg2H     ;  7
    sbc     r_remHL, r_arg2HL   ;  8
    sbc     r_remHH, r_arg2HH   ;  9
    brcs    _udivmodsi4_nep     ; 11/10  remainder got < 0, was < divisor
    sec                         ; 11
_udivmodsi4_ep:
    rol     quotient            ; 12 rotate 1 into quotient
    brcc    _udivmodsi4_pos     ; 14/13
    dec     byteCnt
    breq    bitsDone

byteLoop:
    mov     r_arg1HH, r_arg1HL  ; shift by bytes
    mov     r_arg1HL, r_arg1H
    mov     r_arg1H , r_arg1L
    mov     r_arg1L , quotient
    ldi     quotient, 1
    sbrc    r_arg1L, 0
    rjmp    _udivmodsi4_pos
_udivmodsi4_neg:
    lsl     dividend            ;  1
    rol     r_remL              ;  2 shift dividend into remainder
    rol     r_remH              ;  3
    rol     r_remHL             ;  4
    rol     r_remHH             ;  5
    add     r_remL, r_arg2L     ;  6 raise remainder
    adc     r_remH, r_arg2H     ;  7
    adc     r_remHL, r_arg2HL   ;  8
    adc     r_remHH, r_arg2HH   ;  9
    brcs    _udivmodsi4_ep      ; 11/10 remainder restored to >= 0
_udivmodsi4_nep:
    lsl     quotient            ; 12/11 shift 0 into quotient
    brcc    _udivmodsi4_neg     ; 14/13/12
    dec     byteCnt
    brne    byteLoop
    add     r_remL , r_arg2L    ; restore remainder
    adc     r_remH , r_arg2H
    adc     r_remHL, r_arg2HL
    adc     r_remHH, r_arg2HH
bitsDone:
    mov     r_arg2L , quotient
    mov     r_arg2H , r_arg1L
    mov     r_arg2HL, r_arg1H
    mov     r_arg2HH, r_arg1HL
    mov_l   r_arg1L , r_remL
    mov_h   r_arg1H , r_remH
    mov_l   r_arg1HL, r_remHL
    mov_h   r_arg1HH, r_remHH
    ret                         ; < 500 cycles worst case
sleep
```

How can I keep the speed of non-restoring division without that many additional instructions for divisors with MSB 1?
(As is, their number increases with operand size.)

Comment: Question that may be tackling the same problem: [Non-restoring division algorithm- dividend is smaller than divisor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60152253).

Comment: @njuffa: (The carry flag is definitely used elsewhere (even in 16 bit NR subtract/add…).) I remember *sane* (sort of - libgcc: 39 instruction, ~666 cycles worst case (quotient all 1s), 618 "half 1s"). I'm looking for the first stop *significantly faster* on the road to *no holds barred*: [table driven division](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/537350). Shifting just one byte of the dividend in "the bit-loop" didn't cut it.

Comment: The 8-bit CPU: D. M. Dahle, J. D. Hirschberg, K. Karplus, H. Keller, E. Rice, D. Speck, D. H. Williams, and R. Hughey, “Kestrel: Design of an 8-bit SIMD parallel processor,” in *Proc. 17th Conf. on Advanced Research in VLSI* (R. B. Brown and A. T. Ishii, eds.), pp. 145–162, IEEE CS, Sept. 1997. [[[]]] Related research into integer and floating-point division: E. Rice and R. Hughey, “Multiprecision division on an 8-bit processor,” in *Proc. 13th IEEE Symp. Computer Arithmetic* (T. Lang, J.-M. Muller, and N. Takagi, eds.), pp. 74–81, IEEE CS, July 1997.

Comment: Eric Rice and Richard Hughey, *Multiprecision division: Expanded Version.* Tech. Rep. UCSCCRL-98-10, University California, Santa Cruz, CA, April 1998. 44 pp. ([online](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=349a0aedc37040d9d44944d480c4df0a38fefe6e)). A version with 55 pp. that is likely even more recent can be found [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Richard-Hughey/publication/242384011_Multiprecision_division_Expanded_Version/links/0a85e52d6bdcde5e9c000000/Multiprecision-division-Expanded-Version.pdf).

Comment: caveat: the code uses GCC style `__tmp`/`zero_reg__`, but `ldi` with those is available with reduced cores, only.

Answer (score 2):

The (obvious?) non‑answer of sorts:
One can avoid the code‑bloat apparently necessary for one  special case in *non‑restoring division* resorting to *conditionally subtracting division* instead.
See *A faster drop-in replacement for [libgcc's AVR division](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libgcc/config/avr/lib1funcs.S)* below the horizontal line.

**The** way to avoid a considerable number of additional instructions for *divisor MSB set* is to just prevent the process from ever returning to subtraction while processing dividend bits, *taking a hit* in expected and even in worst case cycle count.
AVR allows skipping the conditional jump implementing that in a suitable way. One more conditional fix‑up is needed before return. This overhead does *not* grow with operand size.

Below *non‑restoring division* disentangled from *dividend&quotient shift by bytes*. Worst case execution times are very similar; but due to the duplicated & bigger bit loop, non‑restoring takes about 59 instructions without movw where *byte shift* takes 39.
The combined *byte shifting non‑restoring division* from the question code block can be modified the same way, raising worst case cycle count back above 500.

```
__udivmodsi4NonRestoring:       ; arg2, arg1 = divmod(arg1, arg2)
    clr     r_remHH
    clr     r_remHL
    mov_l   r_remL , r_remHL
    mov_h   r_remH , r_remHH
    ldi     r_cnt, 33
    rjmp    _udivmodsi4_ep

_udivmodsi4_pos:
    rol     r_remL              ;  1 shift dividend into remainder
    rol     r_remH              ;  2
    rol     r_remHL             ;  3
    rol     r_remHH             ;  4
    sub     r_remL, r_arg2L     ;  5 diminish remainder
    sbc     r_remH, r_arg2H     ;  6
    sbc     r_remHL, r_arg2HL   ;  7
    sbc     r_remHH, r_arg2HH   ;  8
    brcs    zero_bit            ; 10/9  remainder got < 0, was < divisor
    sec                         ; 10
_udivmodsi4_ep:
one_bit:
    rol     r_arg1L             ; 12/11 rotate 1 into quotient
    rol     r_arg1H
    rol     r_arg1HL
    rol     r_arg1HH
    dec     byteCnt
    brne    _udivmodsi4_pos     ; 18/17/16
    rjmp    bitsDone

_udivmodsi4_neg:
    rol     r_remL              ;  1 shift dividend into remainder
    rol     r_remH              ;  2
    rol     r_remHL             ;  3
    rol     r_remHH             ;  4
    add     r_remL, r_arg2L     ;  5 raise remainder
    adc     r_remH, r_arg2H     ;  6
    adc     r_remHL, r_arg2HL   ;  7
    adc     r_remHH, r_arg2HH   ;  8
    sbrs    r_arg2HH, 7         ; 10/9
    brcs    one_bit             ; 11/10 remainder restored to >= 0
zero_bit:
    lsl     r_arg1L             ; 11 shift 0 into quotient
    rol     r_arg1H
    rol     r_arg1HL
    rol     r_arg1HH
    dec     r_cnt
    brne    _udivmodsi4_neg     ; 17/16
    cp      r_remHH, r_arg2HH   ; if r_remHH smaller than r_arg2HH
    brcc    restore             ;     there was a carry
    inc     r_arg1L
    rjmp    bitsDone
restore:
    add     r_remL , r_arg2L    ; restore remainder
    adc     r_remH , r_arg2H
    adc     r_remHL, r_arg2HL
    adc     r_remHH, r_arg2HH
bitsDone:
    mov_l   r_arg2L,  r_arg1L   ; quotient
    mov_h   r_arg2H,  r_arg1H
    mov_l   r_arg2HL, r_arg1HL
    mov_h   r_arg2HH, r_arg1HH
    mov_l   r_arg1L , r_remL
    mov_h   r_arg1H , r_remH
    mov_l   r_arg1HL, r_remHL
    mov_h   r_arg1HH, r_remHH
    ret                         ; ~587 cycles worst case
sleep
```

---

A faster drop-in replacement for [libgcc's AVR division](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libgcc/config/avr/lib1funcs.S)
processing dividend bytes in a nested loop:

```
#define quotient    __tmp_reg__
#define dividend    __zero_reg__
#undef  r_cnt
#define r_cnt       r_arg1HH
__udivmodsi4B:
; no immediates for r0...r15 can be infuriating, especially with
;  callee save for remaining upper registers (r28,r29 + r16,r17 on non-RC)
    mov     dividend, r_arg1HH
    ldi     r_cnt, 0x40-2       ; init loop counters to 4 bytes of 8 bits*2
    clr r_remL    clr r_remH    ; clear remainder
    mov_l   r_remHL, r_remL
    mov_h   r_remHH, r_remH
byteLoop:
__udivmodsi4_loopB:
; shift dividend into remainder
    lsl dividend    rol r_remL    rol r_remH    rol r_remHL    rol r_remHH
; compare remainder & divisor
    cp  r_remL ,r_arg2L     cpc r_remH ,r_arg2H
    cpc r_remHL,r_arg2HL    cpc r_remHH,r_arg2HH
    brcs    __udivmodsi4_epB; remainder <= divisor
; reduce remainder
    sub r_remL ,r_arg2L     sbc r_remH ,r_arg2H
    sbc r_remHL,r_arg2HL    sbc r_remHH,r_arg2HH
__udivmodsi4_epB:
    rol     quotient            ; (with CARRY)
    subi    r_cnt, 2            ; half carry every 8 iterations
    brhc    __udivmodsi4_loopB
; __zero_reg__ now restored (dividend == 0)
;   com     quotient  sets Carry instead of keeping or complementing it
    mov     dividend, r_arg1HL
    mov     r_arg1HL, r_arg1H
    mov     r_arg1H, r_arg1L
    ser     r_arg1L             ; ldi rd, ~0; r16...r31, only
    eor     r_arg1L, quotient   ; touches neither Carry nor Half-Carry
    brcc    byteLoop
; div/mod results to return registers, as for the ldiv() function
    mov_l   r_arg2L,  r_arg1L   ; quotient
    mov_h   r_arg2H,  r_arg1H
    mov_l   r_arg2HL, r_arg1HL
    mov_h   r_arg2HH, dividend  ; the last bytes shift put the quotient MSB here

    mov_l   r_arg1L,  r_remL    ; remainder
    mov_h   r_arg1H,  r_remH
    mov_l   r_arg1HL, r_remHL
    mov_h   r_arg1HH, r_remHH
    ret
sleep
```

Shifting one byte of dividend instead of all four saves three cycles from each iteration of the bit-loop.
Alas, the compromise I chose to keep strictly with libgcc's size & "binary interface" expectations as well as with the "one binary fits all" philosophy adds back one cycle to the bit loop, reducing worst-case speed-up from > 80 cycles to about 53.
(The code ended up one instruction *shorter* than the original.
 Didn't help find a way to recover that cycle lost to *no `ldi` for `__tmp_reg__`* / *`__zero_reg__`* - yet.)

Conceivably, speed-up will be smaller with a variant for "partial single" ints,
and take two instructions more than __udivmodpsi4.

*Shifting dividend bytes* and *non‑restoring division* being independent,
the variant with slicker loop control (almost 30 cycles less) and *Non‑restoring* division look candidates for first and second stops on the way to fast, but large implementations,
combining both as in the question probably is the third.

Comment: __udivmodpsi4 should be faster still than the combined *byte shifting non‑restoring division* - who needs four byte integers, anyway?

Comment: That won't work. You cannot apply `LDI` to `__tmp_reg__`.

Comment: (@emacsdrivesmenuts I have been working with an emulated RC core with `__tmp_reg__` r16. Will investigate finding the time. Using a two instruction sequence there (clr inc) for a total of 39 and claiming a draw with libgcc feels lame.)

Comment: The *no `ldi` for `__tmp_reg__`* /`quotient` issue is more serious than I thought due to applying to `__zero_reg__`/`r_cnt`, too: as is, `__udivmodsi4B` is a drop-in replacement for reduced cores, only.

Comment: For a weirder approach to *controlling an eight-iteration loop nested in a four-iteration one with few AVR instructions* see [revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78214205/4)